# how do i create a /map frame?

Tags: ros, rviz, mapping, tf

I have the following tf tree, but I'm missing the /map frame. Where does it come from? What is supposed to publish it?

[image: existing tf tree]

Answer (score 0):

and welcome to Robotics Stack Exchange. Could you provide why you would like to create a /map frame? This could be done easily creating a tf publisher using tf2 package like this:

```
rosrun tf2_ros static_transform_publisher x y z yaw pitch roll frame_id child_frame_id
```

However, this is just for statics transforms as you can read. Normally the map frame is used to do some localization algorithms, and it wouldn't make sense to say that map and base_footprint transformation is static. Normally, you would like an odom frame as well.

I would encourage you to read [ROS tutorials](https://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials) as well as [REP-105](https://ros.org/reps/rep-0105.html)

Comment: hello thankyou for the help , i need the /map frame and the /odom frame because i am currently trying to do localization with amcl.  But i am new to ros and currently having troubles with the odom and map frame which is currently missing , i triedd static transform but doesnt workout since i need map --> base_footprint / map -->odom--->base_footprint.  Dont have much time left for my project as i wasted too much time on this frames

Comment: i now have the /map frames but im just missing the odom frame

Comment: Odom normally is created by the controller of the wheels of your robot, in order to know where should it be taking into several aspects as the radius of the wheels. If you are working in simulation you can use some plugins or even ros control, but this last one is  a bit harder to set up. Another possibility could be to develop some software in order to create it yourself, taking information such as speed and IMU data, as an example. There are many possibilities out there. The issue here is that you shouldn't post projects tasks as it violates rules in the forum.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, I use [robot_localization](https://github.com/cra-ros-pkg/robot_localization)
package that does both kalman filter and publish a TF tree from "map"->"odom"->"base_link". Also, here is the [Wiki page](http://docs.ros.org/en/melodic/api/robot_localization/html/index.html)